# ¿Cómo se dice "dismissed", en el contexto de una formación de soldados?

Tags: vocabulario

Estoy buscando la palabra o expresión que utilizaría un militar dirigiéndose a un grupo de soldados en formación, para indicarles que quedan "libres", por ejemplo para irse a sus dormitorios. Creo que en inglés es "dismissed", pero sé que palabra se usa en español.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para un grupo de soldados en formación, creo que "rompan filas" es una buena opción.

Comment: Al menos en España es lo que se usa.

Answer (score 5):

No he estado en el ejército, pero en las series y películas se suele doblar como "pueden retirarse".

En [esta lista](http://www.monografias.com/trabajos36/manual-orden-cerrado/manual-orden-cerrado2.shtml) con órdenes militares figura como "**retirar**".